# cannot install plug-ins for Gimp in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

I am trying to install "Upsize.C" and "noise-generator-0.2.5" for gimp.

for upsize.c happens this:

```
christian@mobile02:~/software/gimp-plug-ins$ gimptool-2.0 --install upsize.c
gcc  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gimp-2.0   -o /home/christian/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/upsize upsize.c  -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype   
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCGidxO.o: undefined reference to symbol 'floor@@GLIBC_2.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

trying to install noise generator happens this:

```
christian@mobile02:~/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5$ make
make -C po
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/po'
msgfmt -c -v -o de.mo de.po
de.po:7: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
34 translated messages.
msgfmt -c -v -o pl.mo pl.po
pl.po:2: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
34 translated messages.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/po'
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/src'
cc -O3 -Wall -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gimp-2.0   -o noise-generator plugin.o noise.o events.o interface.o colour.o poisson_gui.o gauss_gui.o uniform_gui.o laplace_gui.o lorentz_gui.o -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype  
/usr/bin/ld: noise.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [noise-generator] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

make install returns:

```
christian@mobile02:~/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5$ make install
make -C po install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/po'
msgfmt -c -v -o de.mo de.po
de.po:7: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
34 translated messages.
msgfmt -c -v -o pl.mo pl.po
pl.po:2: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
34 translated messages.
for L in de pl; \
    do install -v -m 0644 $L.mo "/usr/share/locale/$L/LC_MESSAGES/gimp20-noise-generator-plug-in.mo"; \
done
install: cannot remove ‘/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gimp20-noise-generator-plug-in.mo’: Permission denied
install: cannot remove ‘/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/gimp20-noise-generator-plug-in.mo’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/christian/software/gimp-plug-ins/noise-generator-0.2.5/po'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

now I do not understand what is wrong, I did this operation already several times successfully on previous versions

still I am sure it is something very simple

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a lot late but if you are facing the same issue, if found a solution for noise generator(I didn't use the other plugin yet). In the make file for src directory in noise generator folder add -lm to $(PLUGIN)

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall $(shell gimptool-2.0 --cflags)
LIBS = $(shell gimptool-2.0 --libs)
PLUGIN = noise-generator
SOURCES = plugin.c noise.c events.c interface.c colour.c poisson_gui.c gauss_gui.c uniform_gui.c laplace_gui.c lorentz_gui.c
HEADERS = plugin.h interface.h messages.h
# END CONFIG ##################################################################

.PHONY: all install userinstall clean uninstall useruninstall

all: $(PLUGIN)

OBJECTS = $(subst .c,.o,$(SOURCES))

$(PLUGIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) -lm

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $*.c -lm

install: $(PLUGIN)
    @gimptool-2.0 --install-admin-bin $^

userinstall: $(PLUGIN)
    @gimptool-2.0 --install-bin $^

uninstall:
    @gimptool-2.0 --uninstall-admin-bin $(PLUGIN)

useruninstall:
    @gimptool-2.0 --uninstall-bin $(PLUGIN)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ $(PLUGIN)
```

also for `make install` you need to run as root. So do `sudo su` before giving the `make install` command.

I am not sure if it works for Xubuntu 14.04 but it certainly works on Ubuntu 15.04

Hope it helps

Comment: also I am late:

Comment: also I am late:

Comment: Also I am late:
I tried your suggestion initially with no success.
That I tried 
sudo make clean
sudo make clean install
and it worked, on Xubuntu 14 as well as on Ubuntu 16 (where I had the same problem).

“Upsize.c” is still an enigma, but it is extremely useful
Since I usse versions newer than 12.04 I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
sudo make install
```

Comment: sorry, but this is a bit...